How to Construct PlayerURL for xAPI Package in Custom LMS
We are integrating xAPI (Experience API) into our custom LMS. We tried using the default Tin Can package available on the xAPI website (https://xapi.com/download-prototypes/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=natural_search) with SCORM Cloud. SCORM Cloud returns a playerURL, which is then used to call the LRS API for statements.
Our question is: how can we create this playerURL within our custom LMS?
We understand that the player URL is essential for embedding the xAPI package and communicating with the LRS, but we are unsure about the exact steps or parameters needed to construct this URL in our system.
Any guidance on how to generate or configure the playerURL for the xAPI package in a custom LMS setup would be greatly appreciated.
We were not able to create playerURL necessary for xAPI package

The definition of that launch URL comes from a set of guidelines that were released with a pre-1.0 version of xAPI and have long since been deprecated; they can be found at https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/launch/blob/master/lms_lrs.md
Depending on your intentions and whether you are trying to support 3rd party content or if you are creating your own content or have control over the creation of the content, you may want to consider supporting cmi5 instead. It provides for better launch capability as well as additional specification of xAPI data. See a recent post by me about the types of packages here: https://rusticisoftware.com/blog/what-is-this-elearning-content-package-down-the-rabbit-hole/ and much more about cmi5 at https://xapi.com/cmi5/
